# proxyquire with require.exports = ClassConstructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, proxyquire

If I have a module that exports a single class, how can I mock/stub it with `proxyquire`?

Currently I have the following, which seems to work, but is rather lengthy and doesn't make proper use of `proxyquire`:

**some-class.js**

```
var SomeClass = function(){
  console.log("constructed SomeClass");
}
SomeClass.prototype.shout = function(){
  console.log("HELLO!");
}
module.exports = SomeClass;
```

**my-module.js**

```
var SomeClass = require('some-class');
module.exports.doSomething = function(){
  var a = new SomeClass();
  a.shout();
}
```

**test-my-module.js**

```
// :::: bit I'd like to avoid ::::::
var cls = require('some-class'); 
var SomeClassStub = function(){
  cls.apply(this, arguments);
};
SomeClassStub.prototype = Object.create(originalCls.prototype);
// :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

var myModule = proxyquire('my-module', {
  'some-class': SomeClassStub
});

SomeClassStub.prototype.shout = function(){
  console.log("whisper");
}

myModule.doSomething();
```

Note that I am fairly new to mocking (and testing!) so I might be missing something obvious, but I was hoping that `proxyquire` would deal with my problem itself (rather than me needing to use another library or write the above code).